# I found that I could delete the state parameter in an OAuth request and the response was validated and e-mail was still verified

Tags: oauth, oauth2, burp-suite

I was fiddling around with an OAuth2.0 request on burpsuite and I found that it validated the account even after I deleted the state parameter completely and forwarded the request through burpsuite. I would like to report this as a bug so I want to know if this has any attack vectors.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the site. The state parameter is used for preventing CSRF, and the most typical way [CSRF works on OAuth](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-10.12) is like this:

1. User U is logged into an existing account at some "resource owner" site S (e.g. Github) that attacker E wants access to.
2. E has an account at some authenticating service P (e.g. Google) that they want to use for accessing S.
3. E sets up a malicious site M that U will visit (a watering hole attack) and also goes to S and says they want to link their account on S to their account on P.
4. When U visits M, E gets the OAuth request from S (which typically includes a random state param) and sends it to P.
5. P gets a request to link E's request to an account (it doesn't actually know whose) on S, and responds with a request back to S (typically a redirect URL) containting an authorization code and the supplied state parameter.
6. Rather than visiting the redirect URL itself, E uses M to make U's browser visit the redirect URL, possibly in an iframe or CORS request.
7. S sees a request (due to the redirect URL) instructing it to link the account of the current user (U) to an account on P, with a valid authorization code from P.
8. ***IF S is vulnerable to OAuth CSRF*** S will perform the link, connecting U's account on S to E's account on P. *E can now log into U's account on S via SSO through P!*
9. ***IF INSTEAD S implements CSRF protection correctly*** S will check the state parameter in the request, and make sure it matches one issued to U. If it doesn't (it shouldn't, in this case) or if S can tell that U never requested one, or if the the state parameter is missing (as you describe), then S will reject the request (made to the redirect URI) as fraudulent. *The attack fails; E can't log into U's account.*

Now, with that said, the state parameter isn't *always* required. Here are a few cases where it might not matter (or not matter much):

- S doesn't have any way to create accounts except through P, and doesn't allow linking an existing S account to a different account on P.

  - In this case, you can use the redirect for "login CSRF" - forcing a user to log into your own account rather than theirs - but this is only a useful attack on some kinds of sites and most sites don't protect against it anyhow.
- Rather than using P to authorize users directly, S uses P as an identity provider (e.g. requests the email of the logged-in user from P) and uses the retrieved identity to look up an account on S.

  - As in the previous case, this could be used for logging somebody else into your account (login CSRF), but not for logging yourself into somebody else's account.
- Rather than using the state variable, S protects against OAuth CSRF by something like logging (in its database) the time that a user requests an OAuth link, and only allowing OAuth redirect requests for that user in the next short period (perhaps a few tens seconds to a couple minutes); any OAuth link codes arriving outside the validity window for that user are discarded.

  - This still provides a non-zero window for an attacker to hijack the OAuth process by providing their own code to the redirect endpoint.
  - This is at least as much work as sticking a random state value in the DB (tied to the user) and in the OAuth link request, and verifying that supplied code comes with the expected state value, *so they should just do it that way because it's safer*.

Note that it's pretty common to not actually store the state value in the DB. It can be validated other ways, such as making it a hash of the user's session token (attackers won't know the session token and it should have enough entropy that brute-forcing the hash is ~impossible). In this way, the state is handled by the client (and briefly by the authorization server) rather than requiring any additional storage of state on S.

---

So, to answer your question: It *might* be a bug (it's weird to supply, but not use, a state parameter) but it also *might not* be, or at least might not be a vulnerability. If you can take an OAuth response from a request issued by user A, and use it to authorize access to user B (without swapping their state values), then it's vulnerable. Same if you can, in any other way, use an authorization code (or other OAuth response) issued to A as a way to access B's account (you can easily test this by setting up two accounts yourself, in different browsers, and then catching the OAuth response to A and having B make the redirect/POST response instead).

If you can't do that, it's probably at worst an "informational" finding: "hey, you have a state param but don't seem to use it, is this intended?"

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not enough for the poc. Just make another account and see if you can validate it from the original account.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, I am new to all this